# How to use linq query on list to find last data by name and number c#?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have list but I'm de-serilizing that data into c# class.

I want to filter data and get only those records those are latest date updated  group by name and no.

```
static IMessageReceiver messageReceiver;

            IList<Message> messages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(10);
     List<Myclass> list = null;
                foreach (var message in messages)
                {
                    var mydata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);

                    var newdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Myclass>(mydata);

var result = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.name, x.number })
    .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending((z => z.updatedAt))).ToList();

}
again have to use for loop to process result message one by one 

  public class Myclass
    {
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
```

> newdata will only contain one single value should i need to take list
>   of Myclass while DeserializeObject to filter data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you currectly, this is what you want:

After you de-serialize the data, you get a list, then filter it:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.name, x.number })
    .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending((z => z.updatedAt))).ToList();
```

EDIT:

If you want to do it with only 1 loop you can do something like:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, DateTime>> latestAdded = new List<Tuple<string, string, DateTime>>();

var item = latestAdded.Where(x => x.Item1 == newdata.name && x.Item2 == newdata.number).FirstOrDefault();

if (item == null)
{
    latestAdded.Add(new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>(newdata.name, newdata.number, newdata.updatedAt));
}
else
{
    if(item.updatedAt > newdata.updatedAt)
    {
        item.updatedAt = newdata.updatedAt;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks yes its right - in this case need to use 2 for loop - 1. is to  de-serialize and make a result list and 2. to traverse though this result list and process message again one by one.. 
can I do it on one for loop ?

Comment: Ah, yea, you can use the `Bucket` solution. see my update